# Variable not assigning value in python in while loop

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, while-loop

The following code doesn't seems to work. I want the ini variable to increment, and logically the code seems to do so. But, this doesn't work.

```
def refinexml(xml):
links = []
ini = 0
while xml[ini:].find('<loc>') != -1:
    links.append(xml[xml[ini:].find('<loc>') + 5:xml[ini:].find('</loc>')])
    ini = xml[ini:].find('</loc>')
    print ini
return links
```

Comment: You appear to be parsing an xml document as a string... Is there any particular reason not to use an xml parser, e.g., [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you slice `xml` with `xml[ini:]`, you're getting just the end of it, meaning that `find()` is returning the position of the substring in that *slice* of `xml`, not all of it. For example, let `xml` be this:

```
<loc> blarg </loc> abcd <loc> text </loc>
```

Now, `find('<loc>')` returns `0`. `ini` is `0`, so you capture `" blarg "` and `find('</loc>')` returns `12`. `ini` is set to `12`. On the next iteration of the loop, `find('<loc>')` finds the second `"<loc>"`. You now capture `" text "`. This is where it goes wrong. You slice `xml` at `ini` to get `"</loc> abcd <loc> text </loc>"`. You call `find('<loc>')` on that slice, which finds the second `"<loc>"` in `xml`, which is the first occurrence of that substring in the slice. The problem is that the index of that occurrence in the slice is `12`, not `24`, which is what you want. You're missing the first `ini` characters in the string.

Fortunately, you know how many characters short you are. You need to add `ini`, which you can do like this:

```
ini = ini + xml[ini:].find('</loc>')
```

That, of course, can be shortened to this:

```
ini += xml[ini:].find('</loc>')
```

You can fix your problem by adding a single character.

As mentioned in the comments, though, you should really use an XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

@KSFT explained this very well. I'll just point out you can eliminate a lot of redundant invocations of `find()` in your code using something like this:

```
def refinexml(xml):
    links = []

    start = xml.find('<loc>')
    while start != -1:
        start += 5
        end = xml.find('</loc>', start)
        links.append(xml[start:end].strip())
        start = xml.find('<loc>', end + 6)
    return links
```

But, really, you should just use an XML parser, as even this code makes some potentially dangerous assumptions.